# Autocomplete: How to restrict the number of fields shown in the option box?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I want to populate a large form with 20+ fields. Currently I make a single Ajax call to the DB which pulls in all the possible hits matching the `term`. I do not want all 20 fields of every result to be displayed in the selection box. Just say, name and address. So how can I restrict what is displayed in the selection box ? Then when the user makes a selection, the form will be populated with all the hidden fields. OR should I just make a second AJAX call to grab the additional fields?

```
$('#customer').autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function(request, response,term) {
        var param = request.term;

        $.ajax({
            url: "quotes/customer_search/"+param,
            dataType: "json",
            type:"GET",
            success: function (data) {

                response($.map(data, function(item, index) {

               // I want to restrict the number of these values in the options box to 2
                return item.firstname1+" "+item.lastname1+" 
                "+item.telephone1+" "+item.company_name+" "+item.street+"
                "+item.city+" "+item.province;

                    }
                ));//END Success
            },
        });//END AJAX
    },
```

Comment: Don't return what you don't want displayed....item.firstname+" "item.lastname...... Just don't put things in here you don't want to show.

Comment: @mrunion  Ok, I thought so much. would you recommend that I pull in say the id as well and then do a second Ajax call to get all the fields of the the chosen option ??

Comment: No. Just keep the results of your data call since it has everything. But just don't display what you don't want shown in the drop down. Am I missing something? I may not understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @mrunion I am new to autocomplete so my understanding of it's functionality may be flawed. However, my belief is what you get passed to your select:function(event,ui) *must* be in the return. I want all the data for my form, but I do not want all the data to be returned to the option box. There in lies my dilemma. 

I am thinking the only way of solving it it to include only the id, name . address in the return, and then do a second ajax call with the id.  No ?

Answer (score 0):

I would just invert the logic. Instead of making an ajax call inside the autocomplete source callback, just do the ajax call, and inside the success callback, fill both the autocomplete and the other form fields.

Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "quotes/customer_search/"+param,
    dataType: "json",
    type:"GET",
    success: function (data) {

        $('#customer').autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: function(request, response,term) {
                var param = request.term;
                response($.map(data, function(item, index) {
                    return item.firstname1+" "+item.lastname1;
                }
            }
        };

        //now use data to fill the other values
        //...
    }
});
```